# excel read through GridView Columns not Complete Showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am reading excel file through GridView databinding in my excel i have 600 columns but when excel data bind with gridview its only display 250 columns how to display whole 600 column in gridview i am using this code for it please review it thanks.

```
conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
         OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
         OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
         OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt.MinimumCapacity = 242433;
         cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

         //Get the name of First Sheet
         connExcel.Open();
         DataTable dtExcelSchema;
         dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
         string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
         connExcel.Close();

         //Read Data from First Sheet
         connExcel.Open();
         cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
         oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
         oda.Fill(dt);
         connExcel.Close();

         //Bind Data to GridView
         GridView1.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
         GridView1.DataSource = dt;
         GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use microsoft.office.interop.excel extenstion reference here is a example take a look 
http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/import-excel-data-into-aspnet-gridview_06.html